# redux-toolkit state change in extraReducer does not initiate rerender

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to logout and purge the store at the same time, so on click I dispatch this:

```
dispatch({type: PURGE, key: 'root', result: () => { } });
```

Redux persist catches it, and reports purging the store. Great. 
In another reducer I catch that dispatch, and remove my access token like this:

```
import { PURGE } from 'redux-persist/es/constants';

const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setAccessToken(state: AuthState, action: PayloadAction<Auth>): void {
      state.accessToken = action.payload.accessToken;
      state.expiresIn = action.payload.expiresIn;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {
    [PURGE]: (state: AuthState, action: string): void => {
      state.accessToken = initialState.accessToken;
      state.expiresIn = initialState.expiresIn;
    },
  },
});
```

The PURGE reducer actually is called, and modifies the state, but still no re-rendering happens. so redux must not pick that up. But according to the docs the Redux toolkit uses a Proxy object for the state and does a comparison to see if it's modified.

Things I tried:

```
state = initialState;
```

and

```
state = { ...initialState };
```

Didn't work. The store works, and holds data, other actions work. How do I proceed?

EDIT: Further debugging revealed that my own reducer was called BEFORE the redux-persist reducer, and redux-logger reported that my reducer did not change the state at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be the solution:

```
  extraReducers: {
    [PURGE]: (state: UserState, action: string): UserState => ({
      ...state,
      ...initialState,
    }),
  },
```

I don't understand why, as modifying the state object should work too, according to the [documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createreducer#direct-state-mutation):

> To make things easier, createReducer uses immer to let you write
>   reducers as if they were mutating the state directly. In reality, the
>   reducer receives a proxy state that translates all mutations into
>   equivalent copy operations.

Comment: Any new info on this? Are `extraReducers` mutalbe in the same way as `reducers` are?

Comment: @DmitryPapka, I'm able to use `extraReducers` in the same way as `reducers` to update the state. Works just fine.

Comment: If anyone still ask himself why modifying the entire state doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64505300/6429674

Answer (score 5):

I'm facing a similar issue (not re-rendering) and came by this thread today:
Seems like you can't replace state objects entirely.

From: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers

> Sometimes you may want to replace the
> entire existing state, either because you've loaded some new data, or
> you want to reset the state back to its initial value.
>
> WARNING A common mistake is to try assigning state = someValue
> directly. This will not work! This only points the local state
> variable to a different reference. That is neither mutating the
> existing state object/array in memory, nor returning an entirely new
> value, so Immer does not make any actual changes.

```
const initialState = []
const todosSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'todos',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    brokenTodosLoadedReducer(state, action) {
      // ❌ ERROR: does not actually mutate or return anything new!
      state = action.payload
    },
    fixedTodosLoadedReducer(state, action) {
      // ✅ CORRECT: returns a new value to replace the old one
      return action.payload
    },
    correctResetTodosReducer(state, action) {
      // ✅ CORRECT: returns a new value to replace the old one
      return initialState
    },
  },
})
```

So

```
state = initialState;
```

would be

```
return initialState;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. That totally worked.