# How to reset a redux slice state with Redux Toolkit (RTK)

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying to reset state via a redux action called `resetState`, where I assign the state to the `initialState` variable, however this does not work.

```
const initialState = {
  someArray: [],
  someEvents: {}
}

const stateSlice = createSlice({
  name: "someState",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...someActions,
    resetState: (state, action) => {
      // THIS DOES NOT WORK
      state = initialState
    },
    resetState2: (state, action) => {
      // THIS WORKS!!!!
      return initialState
    },
});
```

When I return the initialState, the state resets properly, but assigning it to `initialState` does not.

Answer (score 17):

Assigning `state = anything` is not correct, regardless of whether you're using Redux Toolkit or writing the reducers by hand.  All that does is point the local `state` variable to a different reference.

RTK's `createSlice` uses [Immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) inside. Immer primarily works by tracking *mutations* to a wrapped value, such as `state.someField = 123`.  Immer also allows you to *return* an entirely new state you've constructed yourself.

So, in this case, what you want is `return initialState` to return a new value and force Immer to replace the old one.

Comment: Hey Mark! I am trying to reset the store made using `configureStore`. I haven't found any answers on that. Can you please drop a comment here? Thanks!

Comment: @PiyushAggarwal what do you mean by "reset the store", exactly?

Comment: Like if I had refreshed the page. I need all slices to have the initial state on logout without refresh. I know how to do it for a single slice. But I am unable to do it for all the other slices at once.

Comment: @PiyushAggarwal that's really an entirely separate question, unrelated to this one :) Can you post that separately, with example code?

Comment: I have added a question. Thank you for the help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608012/how-to-reset-to-initial-state-in-all-slices-in-redux-store-setup-using-redux-too

Answer (score 0):

```
resetState: (state, action) => {
      Object.assign(state, action.payload)
 },
```

Comment: Please refrain from writing a code snippet as an answer. Please take a look at [SO documentation on how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how it's done.