# How to reset to initial state in ALL slices in redux store setup using Redux Toolkit in React.js

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Let's say I have two reducers imported from two slices `authSlice` and `uiSlice`

```
import { configureStore, ThunkAction, Action } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import authReducer from "./auth/authSlice"
import uiReducer from "./ui/uiSlice"

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    ui: uiReducer,
  },
})
```

I am able to reset state of `authSlice` using this code in `reducers`

```
...
const initialState: InitialState = {
  permissions: [],
  loggedIn: false,
}

...
    logout: () => {
      return initialState
    },
...
```

But I haven't been able to find a way to reset to all `initialState`s in all slices.
I want to be able to reset `uiSlice` and `authSlice` to their particular `initialState`s.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset state to initial with redux-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424523/reset-state-to-initial-with-redux-toolkit)

Comment: Thank you @DannyMoshe but this question is not related to my answer.
But there is one answer in there but it does not work for me.
Redux maintainer Mark Erikson will soon be answering my question. I have tagged him somewhere after he asked me to ask a separate question because what I am asking is completely different. Waiting for him.

Comment: @MuhammedJasimTk I did not any response from Mark. I just had two slices in that project. So, I added a resetState function to both the slices and called them from the logout function. `dispatch(logout());' dispatch(resetUiState())`